# AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.compat.tensorflow_stub.io.gfile' has no attribute 'FastGFile'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
if image_path:

# Read the image_data
image_data = tf.io.gfile.GFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in tf.io.gfile.GFile("/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt", "r")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.io.gfile.FastGFile("tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```

this is the code
i got it from https://github.com/burliEnterprises/tensorflow-image-classifier
and other pages that i saw used the same code

but when i run it gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "classify.py", line 29, in <module>
    with tf.io.gfile.FastGFile("tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f: AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.compat.tensorflow_stub.io.gfile' has no attribute 'FastGFile'
```

Comment: You have three places with ...GFile, but the middle one has no mode (‘rb’ in the other cases)

Comment: The error message tells you EXACTLY what you did wrong.  "One of these things is not like the others."

Comment: i dont get it. what should i do ? can u help me pls

Comment: Replace `tf.io.gfile.FastGFile` with `tf.io.gfile.GFile`. Sample code `tf.io.gfile.GFile(
    name, mode='r'
)` . Fore more information about the library find https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile. Thanks!